# How to draw a rectangle in java for android?

Tags: java, android, canvas

I am trying to do a very simple drawing program, where you can draw lines by moving your finger on the screen and now I want to make the program to draw a rectangle as well. I want to create two menu items which determine what I am drawing at the moment. When program starts, it should allow me to draw freely, but when I click the second menu button, I should be able to draw a rectangle. By this, I mean that when I drag my finger, the program draws a rectangle from starting point to the point my finger is dragged. It should always show the rectangle, when it is being dragged/painted.

```
CanvasView.java

    package com.example.androiddrawing;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.graphics.Paint;
    import android.graphics.Path;
    import android.graphics.Point;
    import android.util.AttributeSet;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.view.View;

    public class CanvasView extends View {

        private Paint paint = new Paint();
        private Paint paint2 = new Paint();
        private Path path = new Path();
        private Point point = new Point(); 
        private static List<Path> lines = new ArrayList<Path>();
        private static List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
        private float x;
        private float y;
        private boolean touchStarted = false;

        public CanvasView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
                super(context, attrs);

                paint.setAntiAlias(true);
                paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
                paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
                paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);

                paint2.setAntiAlias(true);
                paint2.setStrokeWidth(5);
                paint2.setColor(Color.RED);
                paint2.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
                paint2.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
                for (Path p: lines)
                        canvas.drawPath(p, paint);
                canvas.drawPath(path, paint2);

                for (Point point: points)
                    canvas.drawCircle(point.x, point.y, 1 , paint);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
                x = event.getX();
                y = event.getY();

                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    // Set a new starting point
                    paint2.setColor(Color.RED);
                    path = new Path();
                    path.moveTo(x, y);
                    touchStarted = true;
                    break;
                    //return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    // Connect the points
                    touchStarted = false;
                    path.lineTo(x, y);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if(touchStarted){
                        point = new Point();
                        point.x =(int) x;
                        point.y = (int) y;
                        paint2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                        points.add(point);
                        touchStarted = false;
                        System.out.println("siin");
                    } else {
                    System.out.println("seal");
                    paint2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    lines.add(path);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    return false;
            }

            // Makes our view repaint and call onDraw
            invalidate();
            return true;
        }

    }
```

This is the code when menu item is pressed

```
MainActivity.java
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.default_drawing) {
            drawMode = 1;
            return true;
        } else if (id == R.id.draw_rectangle) {
            drawMode = 2;
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

I have this code, this allows me to draw freely. But I have no idea, how can I change what is being drawn when I click on another menu item. Hope you understand my question :)

***EDIT:*** Got this menu selection thing working, now if anyone can teach me how to draw a rectangle, would be great ;)

Comment: Why not have two different modes: FreeDrawMode and RectDrawMode.  Have a private DrawMode variable called drawMode.  Allow that to be set using a setter method.  Then in your 'onTouchEvent' method, wrap your current code in a if (drawMode == DrawMode.FreeDrawMode) block and then have an else if (drawMode == DrawMode.RectDrawMode) block to implement your rectangular drawing mode.

Comment: When a user changes the drawing mode option in your menu (code not shown???), just pass in the new mode to the 'setDrawingMode' method.

Comment: Does this answer you're question?

Comment: I got an idea now, but when I have two classes and I change drawMode value in MainActivity.java for example then how can I use this value in CanvasView.java ? Right now I have an error, that drawMode is not declared.

Comment: had to post an answer because the comment was too long.  Please continue communication on my answer instead of here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in CanvasView, create a public enum DrawMode { FreeDrawMode, RectDrawMode };

then create a private DrawMode currentDrawMode;

then a setter method:

```
public void setDrawMode(DrawMode newDrawMode) {
    this.currentDrawMode = newDrawMode;
}
```

Then, in your MainActivity, when a user clicks on the menu item for changing draw mode, just pass in the CanvasView.DrawMode setting that the user selected.

Please note that creating a public enum DrawMode inside the CanvasView class will require you reference it as 'CanvasView.DrawMode.FreeDrawMode' instead of 'DrawMode.FreeDrawMode' from anywhere outside of the CanvasView.java class.

Comment: Should I write public static DrawMode currentDrawMode; instead of private ? Eclipse asks me to do that

Comment: I think I got it to work now. Thank You! :) Now I only have to think, how to do this rectangle drawing ...

Comment: http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/09/introduction-to-2d-drawing-in-android.html